# what's the best way to compress in redhat linux

Tags: passwords, compression, rhel

**os**:redhat enterprise linux

what's the best way to compress a **unicode filename** file with **password-protection**,and which must be **easy to uncompress it in windows**

it will be pretty if it is a **official way** which is provided by redhat.

Answer (score 0):

See this question: https://superuser.com/questions/162624/how-to-password-protect-gzip-files-on-the-command-line

The first answer is the more standard or official way, the second answer is the easier way, but may require installing the zip command.  If it needs to be uncompressed under Windows without installing extra utilities, I would choose the second option.